# How and where to get json and pem file for remote connection to kernel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython, jupyter, spyder

I have a remote server (linux) and my laptop (windows). I'm using Spyder (Python 3.5) on my laptop. I'm trying to run my code on the remote server from Spyder.

From various websites I found out that I need to check `This is a remote kernel` and provide `Connection Info`, `Host name`, `Ssh key` and `Password`
[image]

The `Ssh key` file should be with `pem` extension.

1. How and where do I generate the `Ssh_key.pem`?
2. Where do I get the `kernel-*.json` file for `Connection info`?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) My answers:

> How and where do I generate the Ssh_key.pem?

You don't need a `pem` file if you simply introduce your ssh password there.

> Where do I get the kernel-*.json file for Connection info?

Please read our [documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel) to understand how to generate and get a kernel json file.

Comment: I installed paramiko and now it doesn't crash, but it cannot connect to the server  though I can connect from PuTTy. I waited 10min and it kept saying `Connecting to kernel...` What can be wrong?
Also, how the kernel.json is used, is it copied to the remote server once the connection is established?

Comment: You need to create a kernel in your remote server with `ipython kernel`, then copy its json file to your host and pass that file to the Spyder dialog you showed above.

Comment: that's what I did, but it didn't help. The content of the json file is
`{
  "key": "5561228e-da257d14f408a44b2fa69732",
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "iopub_port": 44161,
  "control_port": 39867,
  "transport": "tcp",
  "stdin_port": 41523,
  "hb_port": 34865,
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "shell_port": 38116,
  "kernel_name": ""
}`

Shouldn't I change the ip?

Comment: Maybe things are blocked by your firewall/antivirus.

Comment: the firewall is disabled. Is there a way to check/debug what's blocking?

Comment: None that I know of, sorry.

Comment: I tried everything and made sure all firewalls/antivurses are disable but it didn't help.
Regarding the connection file kernle.json, shouldn't I change the ip from 127.0.0.1 to the ip of the server?

Comment: No, there's no need to change anything in `kernel.json`. You could check the ssh logs of your remote server to see if there are problems with the connection.

Comment: I did check `auth.log` file and it just have many `error: connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 34865: failed.` messages. `34865` is the port that's specified in kernel.json. I assume this message means that the port is blocked. I'm not a linux user. Can you please advise what can I do to unblock this port?

Comment: I'm no expert on how to handle Linux network traffic. That's usually controlled by `iptables` and I imagine you need to write a whitelist rule for it to allow traffic to the kernel ports. But I don't know how that's done.